# Envoy proxy: I have a requirement to fetch the HTTP headers and send them in JSON format to 3rd party API

Tags: envoyproxy

I have a requirement to fetch the HTTP headers and send them in JSON format to 3rd party API.
The problem is each HTTP stream has different set of headers which are not fixed.
I understand JSON means storing the data in key-value pairs.
So, I need to store key* as header name and value* as header value but the header names are dynamic for each stream means the keys are dynamic.

What is the solution in storing the dynamic keys in JSON format?